# Spring:-HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

Error:-
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.service.onlineServicesImpl.savEmployee123(onlineServicesImpl.java:33)
    com.controller.OnlineBankingController.createNewAccount(OnlineBankingController.java:38)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.67 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.67




spring-distchper-servlet.xml

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="emp" class="com.model.Employee"/>
        <bean id="dmds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="system"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="Oracle@123"></property>
    </bean>  
    <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dmds"></property>  
       <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>hibernate.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>
    <bean id="eDAO" class="com.dao.EmployeeDAO">  
    <property name="template" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>  
    </bean>  
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value> 
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Model Class :-
    package com.model;

```
public class Employee {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String salary;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

DAO Class:-
    package com.dao;

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.model.Employee;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDAO {

    public EmployeeDAO() {
        System.out.println("In a EmpoyeeDAO******************************");
    }

    private HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        System.out.println("In EmployeeDAO setter");
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void save(Employee e) {

        System.out.println("EmployeeDAO Value-------> " + e.getId() + "   "
                + e.getName() + "   " + e.getSalary());

        template.save(e);

    }

}

Service Class:-
package com.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.model.Employee;

@Service
public class onlineServicesImpl {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO dao;


    public void savEmployee123(Employee emp) {

        System.out.println("Employee Value-------> " + emp.getId() + "   "
                + emp.getName() + "   " + emp.getSalary());

        dao.save(emp);
    }

}
```

This my controller Class:-

```
@Controller
public class OnlineBankingController {

    @Autowired
    private Employee emp;

    @RequestMapping("accountcreation")
    public ModelAndView createNewAccount() {

        System.out.println("we are in createNewAccount");
        emp.setId("10");
        emp.setName("pradeep");
        emp.setSalary("500000");

        // dao.save(emp);
        System.out.println("Done");

        onlineServicesImpl obj = new onlineServicesImpl();

        obj.savEmployee123(emp);

        ModelAndView obj1 = new ModelAndView("newAccountCreation");

        obj1.addObject("test", "Testing for spring");

        return obj1;

    }
}
```

//please help
    Can someone suggest what the issue in it why my this code in not working.

Comment: Whenever you're using `@Autowired` components, you cannot instantiate a service class yourself. This line is the problem: `onlineServicesImpl obj = new onlineServicesImpl();`. You should autowire an `onlineServicesImpl` object so `EmployeeDAO` won't be null.

Comment: EmployeeDAO is both autowired and also repository ?

Comment: @JakeMiller : Thank you issue got resolved.

Comment: @georgesvan Thanks you to look into my issue, it got resolved. just want to know we cant use autowired and repository in same class?